# R function with undetermined many arguments

Tags: r

Does anybody know if it is possible to define an own function that takes undetermined many arguments as input? My concrete problem is that I would like to write an own `rbind` function that is able to rbind data.frames with similar rownames (and just assigns new, numerical rownames).

This approach here is obviously wrong, but I hope you get my problem/idea:

```
rbindDF <- function(x){
 N <- length(x)
 # Join x[1] and x[2]
 ...
 # Join x[n-1] and x[n] 
}
```

I tried to find, how it is done e.g. in `rbind` or `sum` but I cannot remember how to see the source code from .Internal functions.

Using a call `rbindDF(list(...))` is maybe one compromise, but I would be happy if it could be done in such a way if three data frames are present `rbindDF(data1,data2,data3)` and e.g. in case of two like this `rbindDF(data1,data2)`.

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: have a look at rbind.data.frame....

Comment: Ups, sorry, you are right, rbind does this... But as @MadScone guessed, this was just motivational for learning, how to write such an R-function in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ellipsis operator (`...`). E.g.:

```
rbindDF <- function(...) {

    df_list <- list(...)
    do.call(rbind, df_list)

}
```

This will allow any number of data frames to be passed in:

```
rbindDF(df1, df2, df3)
```

I take it this question was just about the need for passing an unknown number of arguments rather than the contents of the function itself.

Comment: That was fast, thanks! I haven't thought about using the ellipsis operator to pass arguments internally to a list, really nice! So far I used it only to pass graphical parameters in plotting functions. And yes, I have the concrete `rbind` problem, but was interested how to solve such a problem in general.